# Adding debounceTime to HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular

I've added an http error interceptor to my angular project.

Code is from this example: https://medium.com/@satyapriyamishra111/angular-error-interceptor-4b102f938065

I want to show a toast message if an error was received, but in some cases, i get the same error multiple times and the toast message is also shown multiple times.

I try to add a debounceTime :

```
return next.handle(request)
.pipe(debounceTime(1000),
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  let errorMsg = '';
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    console.log('this is client side error');
    //show toast
  }
  else {
    console.log('this is server side error');
    errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
  }
  console.log(errorMsg);
  return throwError(errorMsg);
})
```

But the toast message is still shown multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, but the answers didnt work for me.
But i found solution that works:

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 
private errorSubject = new Subject<void>();
private error$ = 
this.unreachableErrorSubject.asObservable().pipe(debounceTime(500)); 

constructor() {
  this.error$.subscribe(()=>showToast));
}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      let errorMsg = '';
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        console.log('this is client side error');
        this.errorSubject.next();
      }
      else {
        console.log('this is server side error');
        errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
      }
      console.log(errorMsg);
      return throwError(errorMsg);
    })
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `debounceTime` only happens when there is no error (on happy path). Try adding the `debounceTime` at the end of `throwError`.

```
return next.handle(request)
.pipe( // remove debounceTime from here
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  let errorMsg = '';
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    console.log('this is client side error');
    //show toast
  }
  else {
    console.log('this is server side error');
    errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
  }
  console.log(errorMsg);
  return throwError(errorMsg).pipe(debounceTime(1000)); // add debounceTime here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

debounceTime will just add a delay but will still reach the handler. Did you try the take operator to just work with the first emitted value like this?

```
return next.handle(request)
.pipe(take(1), catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    let errorMsg = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log('this is client side error');
      //show toast
    }
    else {
      console.log('this is server side error');
      errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMsg);
    return throwError(errorMsg);
  })
```